# java heap memory issue

Tags: java, caching, bufferedimage

My application is basically a [photo browser](http://i39.tinypic.com/2lddls4.png). My approach (don't judge me, I am new to java) was to have an `ArrayList` filled with `BufferedImages` and then add the images to the `JList`(to the left).

This is how I get an image :

```
private void getFullImage() {

        BufferedImage im = null;        


        ImageReader imageReader = null;
            try {
                System.out.println("Loading "+original+"...");
                String suffix = Utils.getFileExt(original.getName(), "jpg");
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                Iterator readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix(suffix);
                imageReader = (ImageReader)readers.next();
                imageReader.setInput(new FileImageInputStream(original));
                im = imageReader.read(0);
                imageReader.dispose();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        this.img = im;
    }
```

and then, after I fetched all the data, I would add the images to my `JList` :

```
   Vector vector = new Vector();
   JPanel container = null;
   PhotoPanel pp = null;
   Photo p = null;
   for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
   {
        p = new Photo(files[i]);
        pp = new PhotoPanel(p);
        container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(pp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                       container.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(p.getTitle()));
                                vector.addElement(container);
  }
   plist.setListData(vector);
```

If I have for example 10 files, the app works pretty well. The problem is when I have a lot more images to show. Then I would get an exception : `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. So, I know my approach is a very poor one, and I am wondering how should I take and store all the images and have them to be displayed in the `JList`. Maybe using the cache memory? I read something about `SoftReference` but I don't really know how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew that would push the boundary, but still would not work for an arbitrary number of photos.

Comment: @Jakub I think [@TheLima](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10174948/418556) nailed it.  Noise deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main possible causes for the problem:

---

The first, and which I'm posting more as a warning than as an actual cause in your case, is that an excessive amount of data is being printed on the console with the `System.out.println()`.

I am unsure if it only occurs with NetBeans or all Development tools. But either way, it requires a truly absurd amount of printing for it to be triggered, and i doubt you have that many files loading.

Anyways, if your intent with the `System.out.println("Loading "+original+"...");` line is for a permanent/production logging, rather than something you've put on code just temporarily for development/debug purposes, then you are better off with a proper `Logger`. You can read a TL;DR version of instructions in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16448421/1253136), and you can read further, including the official documentation, through the links provided there.

---

The other cause, which is quite certainly your's, is that you are having too much data loaded at the same time. The solutions are to either:

1. Scale down the images (make thumbnails), and only show the full-size version for the selected image. Please note tough, that this is a fast solution method, and is **not recommended!** As it might still be too much for the system to withstand.
2. Only have the images present at visible portion of the interface loaded (or the thumbnails of said images, for a combined, best solution), and load new images (and unload the others), as the interface is navigated.

Comment: You might 'push the boundaries further' with the first technique by increasing the heap space assigned to the application, but the second approach is far better. +1

Comment: Ok and how do I take the second approach?

Comment: As the user scrolls through the available images, drop one image and add another.  Or load x images and only display x-2, as the user scrolls through, load one more as you display one of the already loaded, but not displayed images.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling a lot with large images (in SWT though) and those OutOfMemory and NoMoreHandles (which might happen even, if there is not enough memory) were a nightmare. I think there is no way, to keep large images or have a lot of images in memory. I agree with Andrew's comment, but just wanted to add, that depending on your requirements you could try to extend a canvas (or whatever there is in Swing) and DRAW your images directly on it, without holding those in memory (similar for PaperClips#PrintPreview). Sure, you will need to have some calculations to layout images correctly, but I think, that in this case you might overcome your problems with memory (but get some other problems:))