# How to attach log4j with web.xml file in a Web Dynamic Project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, log4j, struts

Actually I have confusion in adding a Log4j file with my project. My project is a web dynamic (struts2+spring+hibernate)  project.Now how to add the log4j file with my project.

please could anyone refer me a website or else please give any solution to solve this issue. Currently I need know, how to get Log4j into a web dynamic project.
Thanks in Advance Friends

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use log4j with Struts Spring and Hibernate-Web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764694/how-to-use-log4j-with-struts-spring-and-hibernate-web-application)

Comment: What a server are you deploying?

Answer (score 0):

if your project is maven project, then you need to add apache log4j dependency to your pom and follow below url for configuration

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/

or you can have java util logging which is provided in java standard library, check in below url

[Good examples using java.util.logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950557/good-examples-using-java-util-logging)