# How to set visible another level of logs in console for entire project?

Tags: java, logging, intellij-idea

I have a little JavaFX application where wan't to use *java.util.logging*. I have logged needed information to Level.INFO (currently visible) and Level.FINE (currently not visible) levels. When i trying to compile project via Intellij Idea, i see in console just Level.INFO logs.

Example of code.

```
public class Main extends Application {
   private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "App started. Message's visible");
        logger.log(Level.FINE, "Message's not visible");
   }
}
```

How can i change the console default visible Level without writing for every logger lines of *Handler* code? Maybe some config-file in root?

Logs were written in style of [*grwww* answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950557/good-examples-using-java-util-logging), but there weren't said anything about changing visible Level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [Java Logging Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#a2.2) by Oracle.

*Configuring a Logger Inline in Code*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.logging.*;

public class Main extends Application {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "App started. Message's visible");
        logger.log(Level.FINE, "Message's not visible");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.setLevel(Level.FINE);

        Handler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.FINE);
        logger.addHandler(consoleHandler);

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Note that the level is configured on *both* the logger and a handler.

Information on how to do this came from:

- [Why are the Level.FINE logging messages not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315699/why-are-the-level-fine-logging-messages-not-showing)

*Using a File or a Class to Configure the Logger*

Note that the sample I provided above is for an inline code based approach.  It is also possible to define the logging configuration using a logging configuration class or an external file (or class path resource).  To do this refer to the [LogManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) documentation and the Java Logging Overview previously linked.

> The LogManager defines two optional system properties that allow control over the initial configuration:
>
> - "java.util.logging.config.class"
> - "java.util.logging.config.file"
>
> These two properties may be specified on the command line to the "java" command.
>
> If the "java.util.logging.config.class" property is set, then the
>   property value is treated as a class name. The given class will be
>   loaded, an object will be instantiated, and that object's constructor
>   is responsible for reading in the initial configuration. (That object
>   may use other system properties to control its configuration.) The
>   alternate configuration class can use readConfiguration(InputStream)
>   to define properties in the LogManager.
>
> If "java.util.logging.config.class" property is not set, then the
>   "java.util.logging.config.file" system property can be used to specify
>   a properties file (in java.util.Properties format). The initial
>   logging configuration will be read from this file.
>
> If neither of these properties is defined then the LogManager uses its
>   default configuration. The default configuration is typically loaded
>   from the properties file "lib/logging.properties" in the Java
>   installation directory.

Comment: Thanks. Basically, i had to create "lib/logging.properties" in the root of the project and add to it  
`handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler`  
`.level= FINE`